# Flutter Error - Could not make the context current to acquire the frame

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting the error below when I resize the app window. It doesn't crash the app nor does the frame rate drop at all. I couldn't find a whole lot on this error. Does anyone have ideas?

[ERROR:flutter/shell/gpu/gpu_surface_gl.cc(239)] Could not make the context current to acquire the frame.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('Col text 1'),
                Text('Col text 2'),
                Text('Col text 3'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Center(
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1.0,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Reset'),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51534

Comment: I have read through the thread but didn't help my situation.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: No, I'm still looking at the problem but haven't found a good solution.

Comment: Same error pops when I leave an app idle for ~10 hours.

Comment: 2.5 yrs later, long running organic app started spewing this at me today.  restart/reload didn't help, had to stop and rebuild.